# retrieve json objects in php

Tags: android, http, post

I'm try to send some information in my android app using I tried this code

```
try{

    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("engineer", "me");

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(j));    
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    /*Checking response*/
    if(response!=null)
    {   
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    }
    if(responseBody.equals("ok"))
    {

        //...do something

    }
} catch(ClientProtocolException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but i think there is some error in

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(j));
```

can you please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the JSON instead of a name value pair. The JSON should be the value for another key or you do not use JSON for just a value and a key:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", j.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: it says json object type need to change string type What's wrong?

Comment: sorry, I edited my answer. Your JSON-Object needs to be converted to a string to be passed by POST.

Comment: Thank you friend .Can you please help me to solve this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896232/json-object-post-to-php-script-in-android-app