# json object post to php script in android app

Tags: android, json, post

I tried this android code for send json objects to my website

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("name","name ");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        String format = s.format(new Date()); 
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg",j.toString() ));

       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                               httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

And this php code

```
<?php

$msg=$_POST["msg"]; 

$filename="androidmessages.html";

file_put_contents($filename,$msg."<br />",FILE_APPEND);

$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);

echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

It will show me {"name":"name "} 
but if i use

```
httppost.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
```

it will show nothing.I have no before experince about  json object post but i think something went wrong.I want to send some user information to my website and display it in web page can you please tell me what i need to change to overcome this problem
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you want to pass the data to your PHP-script.

If you want to get the JSON as a string in one variable (and maybe others in addition), then you should not use the content-type "application/json". If you want to only post the JSON without any variable, you can do the following instead:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("name","name ");
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(j.toString());
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

As you can imagine from the code you do not have the JSON in one POST-var only but in total.

Comment: Thank you christian. and i want to know what are different between these 2 methods (String in one variable and Post json without variable)

Comment: Post without variable means you will not get it in your $_POST-array, but have to get it by `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: $msg=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 

$filename="androidmessages.html";

file_put_contents($filename,$msg."<br />",FILE_APPEND);

$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);

echo $androidmessages;




Is this correct?

Comment: why do you need the file? I would just say `echo json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: It will doesn't show anything  but if i use file it will show "Array" but it also doesn't show my details in json object

Comment: I got the answer we need to address array
Thank you very much Christian

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got the answer

```
$msg=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 

$filename="androidmessages_json.html";

file_put_contents($filename,$msg['name']."<br />",FILE_APPEND); 

$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);

echo $androidmessages;
```